# Example MySQL loop to create missing tables

Tags: mysql, loops

I have  mysql DB with incremental table names (ie. table1, table2, table3, tablen).  Somewhere along the way this incrementation has skipped a few and there are gaps.  I want to execute a script which will create the table with the correct table name when the loop finds a missing table.  So something like..

```
for i=1 to 100
  create table if not exists 'tablei'
  ***TABLE FIELD DECLARATIONS***
end
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (might need a few MySql syntax twiddles)

```
Declare @loopvar int
Declare @sql VarChar(8000)
Declare @table_definition VarChar(8000)
Set @table_definition = '(SomeField int null)'
Set @loopvar = 1
While @loopVar < 100
begin
  set @sql = 'Create Table if not exists TableName' + Convert(VarChar(3),@loopvar) + @table_definition
  exec(@sql) 
  set @loopvar = @loopvar + 1
end
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

an answer with all the "MySql syntax twiddles":

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE missing_tables(n INT)
  BEGIN
    WHILE n > 0
      DO
        SET @sql = CONCAT('create table if not exists table', n, ' (value INT)');
        PREPARE cmd FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE cmd;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE cmd;
        SET n = n - 1;
    END WHILE;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
CALL missing_tables(5);
```